# Removing an element from a map that has a map as value

Tags: c++

Say I have a map :

```
std::map<Date, std::map<string, std::list<drinks>>> parties;
```

The string entries are the name of the person coming to the parties. I know erase() exist to remove an element of a map, but how do I delete a person without erasing the Key which contains that person.

For example if parties looks like this:

```
[1]: 2020/12/12 = "Mike" -> ["Water", "Orange Juice"], "John" -> ["Water"]
[2]: 2021/12/12 = "Adriana" -> ["Rhum"]
```

How do I delete the value `John` which is the key at the same time of "Water" without deleting the first key `2020/12/12`?

Comment: `parties["2020/12/12"].erase("John")`

Comment: First step: identify the map from which the deletion should occur. Second step: delete. Pretty basic if you give things the right names. (For example, `auto & soiree = parties[2020/12/12]`?) When complications get in your way, use aliases to eliminate them.